# wpf создать массив user control и поместить GroupBox

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Привет народ, создал User control с помощью конструктора,  теперь мне нужно программно создать массив этих элементов и поместить их в Groupbox или какой либо другой контейнер на другой странице. Видел как это делается в win формах, но нужно использовать wpf. Выручите пожалуйста, заработайте плюсик в карму

Comment: Это в WPF делается не так. Скорее всего, если вам нужно много элеме6нтов, вам нужен ItemsControl. расскажите лучше, какую задачу вы решаете этим.

Comment: У меня есть user control в котором содержится изображение и небольшое описание этого изображения. User control заполняется из бд например для одного элемента так:( var pict = db.Clothe.Select(c => c.Cloth_img)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            UserControl1 img = new UserControl1();
            img.UserImage.Source = byteArrayToImage(pict).Source;)      UserScroll.Content =img ;     а мне нужно создать массив всех для всех элементов из бд и добавить из на страницу

Answer (score 0):

VladD ты космос) Короче, можно правда лучше использовать ListBox.

```
foreach (var num in ClotheList)
           {
               UserControl1 img = new UserControl1();
               img.UserImage.Source =byteArrayToImage(num.Cloth_img).Source;
               UserList.Items.Add(img);
          }
```

Все прекрасно работает